# Appl SF Symbol square.grid.2x2 is always filled

Tags: swiftui, tabbar, visionos

I'm creating a simple `TabBar` on `visionOS`, using `square.grid.2x2` which is supposed to be four bordered squares, but the OS keeps rendering them filled as in `square.grid.2x2.fill`. Am I missing something or maybe this version of the icon is not available on `visionOS`?

```
.tabItem {
    Label("Browse", systemImage: "square.grid.2x2")
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In visionOS, this is an under-the-hood behavior for rendering symbols/icons in the tabbar (I mean an automatic selection of filled symbols instead of outlined variants). I did not find this topic in visionOS HIG, however text explicitly [states](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/tab-bars#app-top): `Prefer filled symbols or icons for consistency with the platform`. It is possible that such a UI design will change in the future.

[image]

Nonetheless, you can disable automatic rendering of filled symbols using `.environment(\.symbolVariants, .none)` modifier.

```
TabView(selection: $model.selected) {
    ForEach(ViewModel.SelectionType.allCases) { selType in
        ContentView()
            .environment(model)
            .tag(selType)
            .tabItem {
                Label(selType.title, systemImage: selType.image)
                    .environment(\.symbolVariants, .none)
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @AndyJazz, I wouldn't have found that one in a million years :) I understand the consistency thing, but depending on the context filled version might not be the best fit (as in this case imho). Thanks!